# Laravel seems to be caching API routes despite my attempts to clear - ideas?

Tags: laravel

I have Laravel 5.3 site.

I added some api routes today but they are not called.

Indeed I have a `NewRouteController` file under `Http/Api`

But the route returns 404 error. The controller is never reached.

There are other routes in `api.php` that work fine (call one of them `api/workingroute`, for instance). But if I comment out their route in `api.php`, they still work!

Here is the api.php file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () { Route::resource('workingroute', 'Api\WorkingRouteController'); });
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () { Route::resource('newroute', 'Api\NewRouteController'); });
```

I think the problem is revealed by `route:list`

```
GET|HEAD  | api/api/newitems                      | newitems.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Api\New RouteController@index                | api            |
|        | POST      | api/api/newitems                      | newitems.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Api\New Route@store                | api            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/api/newitems/create               | newitems.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Api\New Route@create               | api            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/api/newitems/{newitem}      | newitems.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\New Route@show                 | api            |
|        | DELETE    | api/api/newitems/{newitem}      | newitems.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Api\New Route@destroy              | api            |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/api/newitems/{newitem}      | newitems.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Api\New Route@update               | api            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/api/newitems/{newitem}/edit | newitems.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\New Route@edit                 | api
```

Not sure why we have api/api since I don't see anywhere where I would have indicated the route that way, especially since I am just repeating everything that exists for working api routes. Or I suppose since I am using api.php that the prefix is already added.

Also, odd that for my working route, I have a bunch of entries of form `api/route`, but they also have repeat entries of form `api/api/route`

And for routes of form api/api/item we have these sorts of lines

`api/api/item/{item}                     | item.show            | App\Http\Controllers\Api\ItemController@show                         | api`

For routes of form api/item these sorts of lines:

```
 GET|HEAD  | api/item/{item}                         | lesson.show            | App\Http\Controllers\Api\ItemController@show                         | web,auth,admin
```

I looked at routes.php which is holdover from Laravel 5.2 which is still in my folder structure, and we have these sorts of lines:

```
// Api
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api', 'auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
        RegisterResourceRoute('item', 'Item');
```

I think maybe I broke something when I upgraded from 5.2 to 5.3. Strangely enough, the routes defined by this routes.php are the ones of form api/item, and they work. The question now is what to do to get routes back to normal, so that all api routes are of form api/item and all have `web,auth,admin`?

ALso, for what it is worth (not sure if cacheing somehow influences my issue), there is `.gitignore` in the bootstrap/cache folder as well as all storage folders.

And here is cache.php:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache connection that gets used while
    | using this caching library. This connection is used when another is
    | not explicitly specified when executing a given caching function.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Stores
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the cache "stores" for your application as
    | well as their drivers. You may even define multiple stores for the
    | same cache driver to group types of items stored in your caches.
    |
    */

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table'  => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path'   => storage_path('framework/cache'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver'  => 'memcached',
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cache Key Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing a RAM based store such as APC or Memcached, there might
    | be other applications utilizing the same cache. So, we'll specify a
    | value to get prefixed to all our keys so we can avoid collisions.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => 'laravel',

];
```

Ideas?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Use `php artisan route:list` to see what the registered routes and url paths are. Is it not showing in there? try running `php artisan optimize` and re-run the route list command and see if it shows up.

Comment: Problem with route list is it uses PHP CLI and on my MAC the CLI is PHP 5.6 and route:list is generating syntax error. Will upgrade CLI but was trying to just get to the heart of the problem. I created the routes just by editing api.php and creating controller, not using an artisan command, so maybe that changes how Laravel deals with such manual created routes. maybe something in storage folder, but there is no routes.php there.

Comment: You can try to manually clear or rename/move the `bootstrap/cache` folder if present

Comment: Can you post the whole `api.php` route file?

Comment: Hi, yeah, the api route file just has lines of the sort shown in the post. I edited and added controller files. regards, Brian

Answer (score 0):

I suspect several things have happened, but in short check your bootstrap/cache folder. In it I hope you will find a file called routes.php and it has probably been committed into your repo and now you've pulled it down or maybe you even accidentally created it yourself when playing with artisan commands.

Canonically you would use `php artisan route:clear` but if your command line isn't working that won't work, however you should be ok to delete it.

If this is the case, it was created with `php artisan route:cache` but it is advisable only to use that on your production server (possibly as part of a deploymnet script or perhaps as a git hook.)

Ideally there would be a .gitignore (if you're using git) file in the cache folder to avoid this sort of thing being transmitted between different developers.

(Edit - this is only true for later versions of Laravel, but not 5.3 - the OP's version. I leave this here in case other people have the same problem.) It is also possible that someone (if you're working in a team) has done all this on purpose and just not communicated the changes. If so it's also possible that they have specifically set another path for route caching using the environment variable 'APP_ROUTES_CACHE' in which case you'll have to look there.

Sorry this is so complicated - but because of the flexibilty of laravel there are many different ways this could be happening. Please do try them all, though - this is almost certainly a caching issue.

Comment: Hi, my bootstrap/cache folder only has a services.php

Comment: Hi, ok so I looked at cache.php and posted in my post. Also posted results of route:list which are interesting... Seems things are becoming gradually clear, just not sure how to clean up the mess! route:clear doesn't have any effect by the way. Maybe I need to just delete everything in app storage folder? Also, what I am doing now is in localhost. Not on production server. But I set up localhost by copying my production files so maybe I need to do something different with cache.php on localhost?

Comment: While I think my answer is still relevant for most people who will find this page, I'm not sure it's going to help you at this point! I don't any longer think it's a caching issue in your case - it sounds more like you have two route files, almost certainly because of the change from 5.2 - 5.3. This would also explain the extra 'api/' in your routes - they're being added automatially, somehow.
I know little of 5.3
Run a text search on your app for a working route name, and see if it's other than where you'd expect. Also check out: https://mattstauffer.com/blog/routing-changes-in-laravel-5-3/

Comment: At this point I am just trying to get Laravel to forget about all those api/api routes (and in my api.php I will remove the api prefix) and so I am trying to figure out where in the vendor folder is the file that is being used to show the routes. In routes.php, if I add a die statement or something it isn't called, so it seems routes.php is ignored, yet Laravel is seeing the routes specified in routes.php...